# How to change the color of divider of spinner in android?

Tags: android, android-spinner

How to change the color of divider of spinner in android?

I have tried :

```
<style name="My_Theme_Name">
    <item name="android:spinnerStyle">@style/App_Style_Spinner</item>
</style>

<style name="App_Style_Spinner">
    <item name="android:dividerHeight">10dip</item>
    <item name="android:divider">@color/another_blue</item>
</style>
```

I have set the theme of the acitivty to My_Theme_Name.
But this doesn't work.

Please Help.

Comment: Check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10916658/android-cannot-style-spinner-divider)

Comment: How do you use this style for your spinner (can you add that code)?

Comment: @ShwetaK is your problem solved with the given solution?

Answer (score 1):

I think you should try with this link.

[Set Spinner Theme](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13144302/556975)

Problem might be `parent` attribute in defining `themes`.

Thanks.