# Create a spinner which look like the drop down of ASP.Net

Tags: android, android-spinner

I need to create a drop down which has only three values. I have done this using spinner. But it looks like [This](http://www.google.co.in/imgres?q=spinner%20in%20android&um=1&safe=active&sa=N&hl=en&tbm=isch&tbnid=KeaSKKUnALgfUM:&imgrefurl=https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10916658/android-cannot-style-spinner-divider&docid=_Ihi-Vrgo0lm2M&imgurl=https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y57Wc.png&w=400&h=534&ei=EvK2UdixLo2FrgfW14DICQ&zoom=1&ved=1t:3588,r:50,s:0,i:239&iact=rc&dur=2793&page=3&tbnh=198&tbnw=148&start=42&ndsp=26&tx=103&ty=78&biw=1024&bih=679)

But I am trying to create like [This](http://www.google.co.in/imgres?q=spinner%20like%20dropdown%20in%20android&um=1&safe=active&hl=en&tbm=isch&tbnid=xsynP7hlI8r7XM:&imgrefurl=http://go2tricks.blogspot.com/2012/04/android-spinner-dropdown-example.html&docid=339Iw0fd4xMycM&imgurl=http://www.androidhive.info/wp-content/uploads/2012/04/android_spinner.png&w=580&h=638&ei=Jfy2Ud_1E8eOrgfZ-oHwAw&zoom=1&ved=1t:3588,r:37,s:0,i:200&iact=rc&dur=1768&page=3&tbnh=181&tbnw=165&start=35&ndsp=22&tx=63&ty=74&biw=1024&bih=679)

So while click on this it needs to show the values like normal spinner.

I tried with style and setting selector as background but nothing worked and i thought of custom spinner but did not get anything useful.

**Update**

**activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<Spinner
    android:id="@+id/spinner1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:entries="@array/spinner_consigntype"
    android:prompt="@string/spinner_consign" />
</LinearLayout>
```

**Activity_Test.Java**

```
package com.mkyong.android;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class Activity_Test extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_activity__test);
    addListenerOnSpinnerItemSelection();
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity__test, menu);
    return true;
}


public void addListenerOnSpinnerItemSelection(){

    Spinner spinner1 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
    spinner1.setOnItemSelectedListener(new CustomOnItemSelectedListener());
}
}
```

**Listener**

```
public class CustomOnItemSelectedListener implements OnItemSelectedListener {

public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int pos,
        long id) {
    Toast.makeText(parent.getContext(), 
            "OnItemSelectedListener : " + parent.getItemAtPosition(pos).toString(),
            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}

@Override
public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

}
```

In my case I am getting the output as like the first image. But with the downloaded code it is showing the output as the second image.

Comment: in ur activity u have to add some item.(i.e if u want to see some value)...then implement listener in ur spiiner.

Comment: Thanks, Now i have added the listener, For values I am assigning in xml itself. Now onclick of the item it is displaying the selected values as toast. But the UI view is still looking as first image for spinner.

Comment: For the record, what you want is the **Holo** theme, which is the default theme starting with Android 3.0 (Honeycomb). It has nothing to do with ASP.Net

Comment: I have tried setting the theme like this  android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo". But after this background is become black and spinner is still look like the first image that i have posted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

make a selector_spinner.xml  :

item android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/spinner_normal"
 item android:state_focused="true" android:drawable="@drawable/spinner_normal"
 item android:drawable="@drawable/spinner_normal"

use this selector in your layout : main.xml

```
          <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/spinner_selection"
            android:layout_width="0px"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
           **android:background="@drawable/selector_spinner"**
            android:entries="@array/contract_rate_type" />
```

Then in class file,

```
   Spinner sp = (Spinner).findViewById(R.id.spinner_selection);
```

Comment: Thanks, I have added the 9patch image for pressed and focused, which look like dropdown.