# How to get rid of white borders in spinnerDropDownItemStyle when using a custom Spinner?

Tags: android, customization, android-spinner

I created a customer spinner and don't get rid of white spaces when the popup appears:

[image: Popup]

That's how I created the custom spinner:
I copied **simple_spinner_dropdown_item.xml** and **simple_spinner_item.xml** from installation directory to my layout folder and changed the style attributes so that they point to my own style:

**simple_spinner_item.xml**

```
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
    ...
    style="@style/spinnerItemStyle" />
```

**simple_spinner_dropdown_item.xml**

```
<CheckedTextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
...
style="@style/spinnerDropDownItemStyle" />
```

**spinnerItemStyle.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <style name="spinnerItemStyle" parent="android:Widget.TextView.SpinnerItem">
        <item name="android:textColor">#FFF</item>
        <item name="android:textSize">12sp</item>
        <item name="android:background">@null</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

**spinnerDropDownItemStyle.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <style name="spinnerDropDownItemStyle" parent="android:TextAppearance.Widget.DropDownItem">
        <item name="android:textColor">#FFF</item>
        <item name="android:padding">20dp</item>
        <item name="android:textSize">12sp</item>
        <item name="android:background">@drawable/spinner_rectangle</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

**spinner_rectangle.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="rectangle">
    <solid android:color="#333" />
    <stroke
        android:width="0dip" />
</shape>
```

The spinner is simply referenced within the layout file of the Activity:

```
        <Spinner 
            android:id="@+id/preferences_spinner_language"
            android:background="@drawable/spinner_dropdown" />
```

And I don't use a custom Adapter, just the usual ArrayAdapter where I use the both resources from above and **not** the Android resources:

```
Spinner spinner = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.preferences_spinner_language);
ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.preferences_language_array, R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
adapter.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
```

I guess that there is some underlying ImageView which produces these white borders. How can I access it and get rid of these border or colorize them? I would prefer a solution where I don't have to create an own ArrayAdapter.

Comment: hope it helps! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10916658/android-cannot-style-spinner-divider/13144302#13144302

Comment: Unfortunately not, because there is no Theme.Holo in Android 2.3.3. And `android:dropDownListViewStyle` does not exist in my parent theme I use. I already created my own theme due to other reasons and derive from `parent="android:Theme"`

Answer (score 0):

In your theme, override the `android:dropDownListViewStyle` style. Eg:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo">
    <item name="android:dropDownListViewStyle">@style/MySpinnerStyle</item>
</style>

<style name="MySpinnerStyle" parent="android:style/Widget.ListView.DropDown">
    <item name="android:divider">#FFEEEEEE</item>
    <item name="android:dividerHeight">1dp</item>
</style>
```

Comment: I don't know how this should work. I already overwrite my theme since I use a custom theme for my whole app (parent="android:Theme"). And in my current theme, I have no items like android:dropDownListViewStyle (content assist of Eclipse doesn't show such suggestions). That's why all other threads with similar questions were not helpful to me.

Comment: If your parent theme is `android:Theme` this value is already set for you. Have you tried adding the `android:dropDownListViewStyle` tag to your custom theme?

Comment: I tried to use my own theme as parent or parent="android:Theme", because there is no Theme.Holo in Android 2.3.3, but the divider stays white. (Although I changed in AndroidManifest my custom theme to the derived theme). I tried to add `<item name="android:dropDownListViewStyle">@style/MySpinnerStyle</item>` with its declaration to my custom theme, but still no change.

Comment: I know it's been years, but have you solved this issue? I'm having the exact same problem and I've tried everything around, but no luck :/