# How to add space between custom spinner items?

Tags: android, spinner, android-spinner

I've followed this tutorial [Android Widgets: Custom Spinner in Android](http://www.edureka.co/blog/custom-spinner-in-android/) and made a custom `Spinner` that has an image and a text view as items, but for some reason there is no space between the items.

At the moment it looks like that when it's not clicked (which is fine):

[image: Custom spinner not clicked]

And when I click it, it looks like that:

[image: Custom Spinner clicked]

While the default one has plenty of space between the items:

[image: Default spinner clicked]

This is the `xml` code for the spinner:

```
<Spinner
    android:id="@+id/languageSpinner"
    style="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.Spinner"
    android:layout_width="110dp"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="30dp"
    android:prompt="@string/select"
    android:spinnerMode="dropdown"/>
```

And this is the xml for the custom row layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/icon"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/language"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Does anybody have an idea what I do wrong?

**EDIT**: After some of the suggestions, the space between the items is added but then the item that is selected in the spinner cannot be seen properly, I am attaching an image:

[image: Custom spinner with padding 10 on the layout]

Comment: try with padding it will work

Comment: @Lakhan If I add padding, it also adds it on the first item and then changes the look when it's not clicked.

Comment: Did u apply marginTop ?

Comment: [Check](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10916658/android-cannot-style-spinner-divider) - Use a transparent divider.

Comment: You can also give checked - unchecked layout for spinner.

Comment: @PiyushGupta Yes, but it's the same outcome as the padding - it changes the look of the first / selected item, when the spinner is not clicked.

Comment: @Apostrofix where you are adding the data... do something like this  dataAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line);

Comment: `PaddingTop` gives top margin of spinner content(TextView) while `marginTop` give top margin for Spinner itself.

Comment: http://fatoumatabintou.blogspot.in/2012/02/custom-spinner-with-icon-and-text.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

custom row layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <LinearLayout 
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_margin="10dp">
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/icon"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/language"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"/>
    </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

You only need add the attribute **lineSpacingExtra** in your textview.

Example:

```
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/language"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
        android:lineSpacingExtra="3dp/>
```

--> **android:lineSpacingExtra="3dp**

Comment: I would also use that attribute. Nice one ;)

Comment: It's nice indeed, but unfortunately nothing changes when I add it, even if I increase it to let's say 50dp.

Comment: You can try to add paddin in your LinearLayout then. 

Example:
android:padding="5dp"

Answer (score 0):

try this way

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >


    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/icon"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dip"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dip"
        android:layout_marginLeft="15dip"/>


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/country"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dip"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dip"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dip"
        android:textColor="#000000" />


</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

just select this layout **simple_list_item_1**

```
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,data); //add this layout
spinner_state.setAdapter(adapter);
```

that's all... enjoy your coding...