# Android spinner divider color

Tags: android

I have a spinner styled like this

```
<style name="OptionsSpinner" parent="android:Widget.Spinner">
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/spinner_background</item>
    <item name="android:spinnerMode">dropdown</item>
    <item name="android:dropDownListViewStyle">@style/SpinnerDropdown</item>
</style>

<style name="SpinnerDropdown">
    <item name="android:divider">#ff0000</item>
</style>
```

but the style SpinnerDropDown doesn't have any effect, the divider is grey or whatever the default is. How do I style the dividers in a spinner?

Answer (score 51, accepted):

You are using this style directly in the `style` property of your `Spinner` widget?
If so, that's why it's not working. You should style the divider using the `theme` of your application.

To style the divider, do the following:

In your application theme you should have the `item` `android:dropDownListViewStyle`:

```
<style name="applicationTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light">
    <item name="android:dropDownListViewStyle">@style/mySpinnerStyle</item>
</style>
```

And, the style of the divider (mySpinnerStyle) is defined in:

```
<style name="mySpinnerStyle" parent="android:Widget.ListView.DropDown">
    <item name="android:divider">#00ff00</item>
    <item name="android:dividerHeight">1dp</item>
</style>
```

Now you have a green divider on your `Spinner` :)

Comment: The styling applied here works when the Spinner is set to it's default mode which is dropdown, if the Spinner mode is set to dialog then the styling has no effect !

Comment: Why doesn't the style get applied when it is used directly in the style property of the spinner? Any idea?

Comment: What if I have two spinners in my activity which need different divider colors? In this case the method which you suggested will not work

Comment: @DevAndroid See my answer below

Comment: Where is the answer below?

Comment: @DevAndroid ,  see my answer  https://stackoverflow.com/a/47266365/4543133