# Spinner doesn't show dividier

Tags: android, android-layout, dialog, android-spinner, android-styles

From some reason, Android ignoring my spinner property of a divider, the divider is not showing.
I already check this post: [Android spinner divider color](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18641514/android-spinner-divider-color)

at first I thought maybe it's my *android:spinnerMode="dialog"* 
but nothing!

Here is my spinner code:

```
        <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatSpinner
        android:id="@+id/search_category_spinner"
        android:layout_width="140dp"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:prompt="@string/category_search_spinner_header"
        android:spinnerMode="dialog"
        style="@style/mySpinnerStyle"
        android:layout_below="@id/text_layout_free_search"
        />
```

and here is my Theme and style:

```
    <style name="AppTheme.Base" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/primaryColor</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/primaryColorDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/accentColor</item>
    <item name="android:textColorPrimaryInverse">#FFFFFF</item>
</style>


<style name="AppTheme" parent="AppTheme.Base">
    <item name="android:dropDownListViewStyle">@style/mySpinnerStyle</item>
</style>


<style name="mySpinnerStyle" parent="Widget.AppCompat.Spinner.Underlined">
    <item name="android:divider">#00ff00</item>
    <item name="android:dividerHeight">4dp</item>
</style>
```

And my v21\style.xml:

```
    <style name="AppTheme.Base" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="android:colorPrimary">@color/primaryColor</item>
    <item name="android:colorPrimaryDark">@color/primaryColorDark</item>
    <item name="android:colorAccent">@color/accentColor</item>
    <item name="android:textColorPrimaryInverse">#FFFFFF</item>
</style>

<style name="AppTheme" parent="AppTheme.Base">
    <item name="android:dropDownListViewStyle">@style/mySpinnerStyle</item>
</style>

<style name="mySpinnerStyle" parent="Widget.AppCompat.Spinner.Underlined">
    <item name="android:divider">#00ff00</item>
    <item name="android:dividerHeight">4dp</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer you're talking about is working for the dropdown style. If you are looking for the dialog style, you probably have to use a custom layout.