# How to add divider between dropdown items in material spinner?

Tags: android, android-layout, material-design

I am facing problem to add divider/separator between dropdown items in material spinner.

```
<fr.ganfra.materialspinner.MaterialSpinner
            android:id="@+id/purpose_spin"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:prompt="@string/purpose"
            app:ms_multiline="false"
            app:ms_hint="@string/purpose"
            app:ms_floatingLabelText="@string/purpose"
            app:ms_arrowSize="16dp"
            app:ms_alignLabels="false" />
```

Comment: refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4569751/how-to-show-divider-between-spinner-items

Comment: i am also want this answer still not found , all answer suggestion is appcompat not material componenets if you found kindly comments below .

Answer (score 0):

Go to `style.xml` and add this line :

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->

   <item name="android:dropDownListViewStyle">@style/SpinnerStyle</item>
</style>
```

After add this code in `style.xml`

```
<style name="SpinnerStyle" parent="Widget.AppCompat.ListView.DropDown">
    <item name="android:divider">#212121</item>
    <item name="android:dividerHeight">1dp</item>
</style>
```