# how to set spinner text in center and set divider also

Tags: android, android-studio, android-spinner

I want to set a spinner text center and set a divider also. There is a problem in set text at the center and set divider.  Also the spinner items and spinner values are coming from a server json.

This is my code:

**XML:**

```
<Spinner
    android:id="@+id/txtSpinner"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    style="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.Spinner"
    android:dropDownVerticalOffset="28dp"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    android:layout_height="45dp"
    />
```

**Java code:**

```
   private void getSpinnerData() {
    final ProgressDialog loading = ProgressDialog.show(this, "Loading Data", "Please wait...", false, false);
    loading.setCancelable(true);
    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(spinner_url,
            new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                        loading.dismiss();
                    JSONObject j_obj = null;
                    try {
                        j_obj = new JSONObject(response);
                        result = j_obj.getJSONArray("data");
                        getdata(result);
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            },
            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                }
            });
    RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
    requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
}
private void getdata(JSONArray j) {
    for (int i = 0; i < j.length(); i++) {
        try {
            JSONObject json = j.getJSONObject(i);
            spinnerlist.add(json.getString("category"));
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    //Setting adapter to show the items in the spinner
    txtSpinner.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(TextActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, spinnerlist));

}
```

**current output**

[image]

**What I want**

[image: this]

Comment: Maybe here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4569751/how-to-show-divider-between-spinner-items

Comment: On a side note, why are you using Holo and not Material Design?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

my answer is here its working.....

create new Style

```
<style name="ThemeName" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.Spinner">
    <item name="android:dropDownListViewStyle">@style/mySpinnerStyle</item>
</style>
<style name="mySpinnerStyle" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Spinner.Underlined">
    <item name="android:divider">#000</item>
    <item name="android:dividerHeight">1dp</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can customize Spinner to make it whatever you want. If you just want to set divider, you just need to customize spinner_dropdown_item.xml with divider.